# Glassfish - Resource Injection not working

Tags: jdbc, dependency-injection, glassfish, datasource

Using NetBeans IDE and Glassfish Server. For some reason I can't get a DataSource injected (have tried a million variations).

```
private DataSource iserver;
@Resource(name="jdbc/iserver", type=DataSource.class)
public void setIServer(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.iserver = dataSource;
}
```

(I already tried adding @Resource annotation directly to the field). The connection pool and jdbc resource are configured on Glassfish, and for the time being, I have added the workaround code (in the same class):

```
ctx = new InitialContext();
iserver = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/iserver");
```

The workaround code works perfectly. I don't see any *obvious* relevant errors in Glassfish log. I do see this, but not sure it's related:

**name cannot be null at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:405) ** at javax.management.ObjectName.(ObjectName.java:1403) at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.ProxyHandlers.getRuntimeProxyAttrs(ProxyHandlers.java:289) at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.ProxyHandlers.getProxyAttrs(ProxyHandlers.java:273) at ...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're in a session bean or injection won't work.

Here's an example of how I inject

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/my_db") private DataSource dataSource;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm totally new to this - when you say "make sure you're in a session bean", where exactly does that need to be specified (eg. does my class have to extend SessionBean?)

Comment: Injection only works if you're within a session bean not a pojo (plain ol java object). So, if you're injecting you need to be in a class that implements your remote interface
i.e.:

    @Stateless(mappedName = "YourSessionBean")
public class YourSessionBean implements YourSessionRemote {

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Choose the option `"name"` by `"lookup"` `-->`

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:global/env/jdbc/__default")
DataSource dataSource;
```

Comment: Isn't the docs' misleading a bit? The documentation of the `name` attribute says: _The JNDI name of the resource._ So thanks, you saved many hours for me!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, bean scope (session) has no effect on this as long as the bean is managed.